# Google Map en tabhost

Tags: android, google-maps

estoy intentando realizar una aplicación móvil que me posicione en un mapa los parques de una ciudad. Consigo que me los posicione correctamente, sin embargo, ahora querría poner ese mapa en una tab. 
Para ello hago lo siguiente en el oncreate de la actividad de tabs:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    tabHost= (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),android.R.id.tabcontent);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(getString R.string.label_listado)),ListadoFragment.class, null);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(getString(R.string.label_geoposionar)),MapsFragment.class, null);

}
```

La clase MapsFragment:

public class MapsFragment extends Fragment  {

```
private Callbacks mCallback = null;
public ArrayList<Parque> listado;

public static MapsFragment newInstance() {
    MapsFragment fragment = new MapsFragment();

    return fragment;
}

public MapsFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=null;
    GoogleMap googleMap=mapa.newInstance(listado);
    mapa.newInstance(listado);
    mapa.onMapReady(googleMap);

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps,
        container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

       }

 public interface Callbacks {
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap);


 }
}
```

Y la actividad del mapa:

```
 public class MapsActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity   
 implements OnMapReadyCallback {
 public GoogleMap mMap;
 public static String coordenadas="";
 public ArrayList<parque> listado;

 public  GoogleMap newInstance(ArrayList<parque> listado) {
    listado=listado;
   return mMap;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
           SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)     
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    onMapReady(mapFragment.getMap());
 }


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   mMap = googleMap;
   //mMap=((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
           ArrayList<parque> listado=listado;
    String defecto="";
    String[] latlong = bar_defecto.split(" ");
    double latitud = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
    double longitud = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
    LatLng defecto_latlong=new LatLng(latitud,longitud);
    LatLng coordenadas;
    for(int x=0;x<listado.size();x++) {
        parque p = listado.get(x);
        coordenadas = bar.getmCoordenadas();
                   if (coordenadas.compareTo("-")!=0 && coordenadas!=null && bar.getmNombre()!=null) {
            latlong = coordenadas.split(" ");
            latitud = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);

            longitud = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);

            coordenadasBar = new LatLng(latitud, longitud);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordenadas).title(bar.getmNombre()));
        }
    }
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(defecto_latlong,  
   12.0f));

  }
}
```

¿Cómo puede insertar en una tab un mapa?

Comment: Mírate el elemento ViewPager https://amatellanes.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/android-ejemplo-de-viewpager-en-android-parte-1/ o bien si en Android Studio creas una nueva actividad y seleccionas "tab activity" podrás importar el fragment  map que tienes.

Comment: No puedo crear una tab activity ya que la versión mínima que se necesita es la 13 y yo tengo la api 10.

Comment: Lo primero es que te aconsejo subir de API la 10 es muy vieja  , ponla en la api de android 4.0.1 te servirian la mayoria de dispositivos
Segundo lo primero que tienes que hacer es crear un tabhost y dentro de de un tab , colocas el xml del fragment y listo ya eso  es todo..
Ya realice esto una vez con un mapa asi que si nesecitas ayudas me puedes contactar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Encontré la solución de como crear un map fragment y poder insertarlo en una tab. Es la respuesta 2 de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager

La copio aquí por si desaparece en un futuro:

```
The following approach works for me.

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

/**
 * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
 */
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// inflat and return the layout
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_info, container,
        false);
mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

try {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
// latitude and longitude
double latitude = 17.385044;
double longitude = 78.486671;

// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
        new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

// Changing marker icon
marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

// Perform any camera updates here
return v;
}

 @Override
 public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   mMapView.onResume();
 }

 @Override
 public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   mMapView.onPause();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
 mMapView.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public void onLowMemory() {
  super.onLowMemory();
  mMapView.onLowMemory();
 }
}


fragment_location_info.xml



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: La idea es publicar aquí mismo la solución ya que si colocas solo la url con tu "solución" y si algún día deciden retirar/eliminar ya sea el post todo el sitio de nada serviría para los futuros usuarios con el mismo problema, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La opción para agregar tu mapa dentro de un tab no debe ser usando Activity, debe ser un Fragmento, no es opción usar una actividad.

Puedes realizarlo con **[TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)** que viene dentro de la librería "Design" de Android y un viewpager.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se tiene un ejemplo (inglés):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager

Comment: Ok, ¿Y que tendría que modificar para hacer el mapa en un fragmento? Ya que como tengo hecho el MapsFragment no me llama al método que geoposiciona : onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)